# Spark SQL, HIVE and connection pool

Tags: hive, connection-pooling, apache-spark-sql

I've a spark ob that is computing a set of Dataframes from jdbc (postgreSQL) and Cassandra. 
Then, final RRDs are registered as TempTable in Hive context to be used/served later by an embedded thrift server.
From now on, RRDs will be accessed as tables in Hive context by an external application via jdbc:hive

from logs seems that connections to DBs are closed/reopened.
Is there any way to set-up a connection pool?
Can someone point to a good example?

Thanks!